# Perl concatenation of variables for path from a different file

Tags: perl, variables, concatenation, redhat

I have a simply things (usually) that doesn't work, it's the concatenantion of variables in Perl. I have to create a script in Perl for a Redhat's server.

I have two files:

- **file.properties** : which contain somes variables with path, like

  remotePath=/opt/applicaton/logs/backup
  logType=statistics.log
- **testfile.pl** : wich contain the code for the concatenation of the variables to create the real path..Here is the code

---

```
#get the variables
if ( $type =~ /remotePath/ ) {
    $remotePath = $val;
}
if ( $type =~ /logType/ ) {
    $logType = $val;
}

$logName = "tcf_.$logType";

#we would like to add the date at the logType and a prefix..
for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#ARGV; $i++ ) {
    if ( $ARGV[$i] =~ /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/ ) {
        $dateFormatLog = sprintf( "%s-%s-%s", $1, $2, $3 );
    }
}
#I tried to print each variable separately it works well, but not the concatenation..

my $finalPath = "$remotePath/$logName.$dateFormatLog";
#or
my $finalPath = $remotePath . '/' . $logName . $dateFormatLog;

print $finalPath;
```

The **result expected is /opt/applicaton/logs/backup/tcf_statistics.log.2014-10-13.zip**
But I have something like

```
.2014-10-13 tics.logwas/logs/backup
```

or

```
2014-10-13istics.logwas/logs/backup
```

I don't know why the result of the concatenation is a such things, if someone have an idea it will be very helpful !

Thanks by advance,

Jimmy

Comment: Where does the `was` come from? You say you have `remotePath` set to `/opt/applicaton/logs/backup`, but the path in the output ends with `was/logs/backup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it looks like your data comes from a file that originated on a Windows (or possible a Mac) system. Such systems have a CR at the end of each line as well as, or instead of, an LF, which won't be removed by `chomp` on a Linux platform.. You don't show how you read the data, but the best way to fix such files is to use `s/\s+\z//` instead of `chomp` as you read each line.

Secondly, you are expecting the filename to look like `tcf_statistics.log.2014-10-13.zip` but the value of `$logName` will be something like `tcf_.statistics.log`, so you have an extra dot `.` in there after `tcf_`.  You should set up the value like this

```
my $logName = "tcf_$logType";
```

You also need to incorporate the value of file extension `.zip` somehow; probably like this.

```
my $finalPath = "$remotePath/$logName.$dateFormatLog.zip"
```

That should get your code working.

Comment: yeah good point, maybe use Data::Dumper to look at the control characters

Comment: @Vorsprung: [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) is a much superior choice